# strange LogCat error

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

working with Eclipse 3.6.2. When opening LOGCAT this message shows:

"Copy" did not complete normally.  Please see the log for more information.
Argument not valid

and nothing else will appear in the LOGCAT window....

Comment: Is this with an emulator running or a device hooked up? And is there an error logged in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem with

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: 1.2.2.20100216-1730
Build id: 20100218-1602

It first happened when Google introduced the new Logcat view.

It's still happening for me with:

Android Development Toolkit

Version: 15.0.1.v201111031820-219398

They left the old Logcat, although it's now called Logcat (deprecated).  However the deprecated Logcat works fine for me.

Annoyingly, if I just hide the new Logcat view it reappears, so removed it from the bottom tabs in eclipse, and then keep the tab minimized, and just use the deprecated view.